# why doesn't spritecollide method work?

Tags: python, pygame

In my code, I wanted to use the spritecollides method but I got the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/lanik2009/Documents/pygame testing.py", line 76, in <module>
>
> hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, obstacles, False)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 1645, in spritecollide 
> default_sprite_collide_func = sprite.rect.colliderect
>
> AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'rect'

My code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
  
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 128)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)

w = 500
h = 500

x = 15
y = 480

vel = 5
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

square = pygame.image.load(r'/Users/lanik2009/Downloads/square.PNG')
square = pygame.transform.scale(square, (46, 40))
triangle = pygame.image.load(r'/Users/lanik2009/Downloads/triangle.PNG')
triangle = pygame.transform.scale(triangle, (46, 40))

squareSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
squareSprite.image = square
squareSprite.rect = square.get_rect()

triangleSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
triangleSprite.image = triangle
triangleSprite.rect = triangle.get_rect()

def drawer():
    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(triangle, (100, 460))
    screen.blit(square, (300, 460))
    
jump = False

obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()

obstacles.add(squareSprite)
obstacles.add(triangleSprite)

running = True

while running:
      
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel

    if jump == False:
        y = 480
        
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= 40
        jump = False
        
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        jump = False
        
    drawer()
    
    player = pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (x, y), 10, 500)
    pygame.display.update()

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, obstacles, False)
    if hits:
        running = False

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

As in your previous question, your error message tells you exactly what is wrong.

> AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'rect'

This means that pygame expected you to give it an object that has an attribute called "rect". Instead, you gave it a `pygame.Rect`. `pygame.Rect`, naturally, does not have an attribute called "rect". It *is* a `Rect`, it doesn't *have* a `Rect`.

Where did this `Rect` come from? If you [read the documentation for `pygame.draw.circle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle), you'll see it says:

> Returns:
> a rect bounding the changed pixels, if nothing is drawn the bounding rect's position will be the center parameter value (float values will be truncated) and its width and height will be 0

So this line:

```
player = pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (x, y), 10, 500)
```

...sets `player` to be a `Rect` object.

The `spritecollide` function expects you to pass it a `Sprite` and a `SpriteGroup`. You passed it a `Rect` and a `SpriteGroup`.

You can draw your player as a sprite instead of a circle if you want to use the `spritecollide` function, or you can use a different collision checking function to test a `Rect` against members of a `SpriteGroup`.

Comment: For context: I have never written a single line of Python code in my life. This doesn't take any special knowledge of Python to understand. You just need to read your error messages and read the documentation. Please get in the habit of doing so, and you'll find you're able to solve simple issues like this on your own, much faster than posting here.